# Change crm default action from odoo v14 E

Tags: odoo, default

I'm new to odoo technical features. I'm not developer or advanced odoo user, but I wish to customize opportunity names when created.

I found this action:

[image: CRM action]

Is it possible to change the context value to set default_name with something like self.get() and pass selected (partner_id.name or false) to it?

Default context value from view:

{'default_type': 'opportunity','search_default_assigned_to_me': 1, }

Also if you can help me extend this to get a text like: "{if(partner_id.is_company = True) {partner_id.name} elseif (partner_id.is_company = False && parent_id is not null) {partner_id.parent_id.name} else {False} // if else {False} doesn't work, is there a way to keep default odoo behaviour where name becomes "Client's opportunity".

Hope it is understandable, I have been researching but im new to coding and haven't got any futher from here.

** I haven't learned yet to do modules and install them to odoo, so I have been just customizing through UI, please guide me on how to solve this from UI or Odoo Studio.

I have tested:

Adding the next statement to the domain: {'default_name' : context.get('partner_id.name',False),}